# Moodle Campus Theme - Changing the landing page after login and filter out courses on the basis of language selection

Tags: php, moodle

How can we change the default landing page in Moodle campus theme after login? If that possible to filter out the courses based upon the language selection? If yes, then how? I am currently using Moodle 2.9.0.